# CCMenuItemSprite CCLabelBMFont selector not working

Tags: menu, cocos2d-iphone, selector

I am having issues with making the selector in my code below work. Even logs don't display anything. How can I solve this issue?

```
-(void)displaySettingsMenuItems {

CCSprite *buttonHolder = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"buttonHolder.png"];
buttonHolder1.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
[self addChild:buttonHolder z:ZPos];
CCMenuItemSprite *instructionsItemSprite = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithTarget:self selector:nil];

CCLabelBMFont *instructionsLabelFont = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"instructions" fntFile:@"TestingFont.fnt"];
CCMenuItemLabel *instructionsItemLabel = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:instructionsLabelFont target:self selector:@selector(instructionsLayer)];

instructionsLabelFont.position =ccp(screenSize.width/2, 0.99*screenSize.height/2);
[instructionsItemSprite addChild: instructionsItemLabel z:ZPos];
[self addChild:instructionsItemSprite z:ZPos];
}
```

the method for the selector:

```
-(void)instructionsLayer {
CCLOG(@"code is okay");
[[MenuManager sharedMenuManager] runWithPrePlayMenu:kInstructions];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add your instructionsItemLabel menu item to a CCMenu (not a CCMenuItem), then add the menu to your scene. The CCMenu is a place holder for the menu items (one or many) and extends the CCLayer class. It provides the touch handling for the menu items it embeds, and the logic to invoke its menu items when there are touch events that concern a specific menu item.

```
-(void)displaySettingsMenuItems {

    CCSprite *buttonHolder = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"buttonHolder.png"];
    buttonHolder.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);  // <- you had buttonHolder1 ivar 
    [self addChild:buttonHolder z:zPos];

    CCLabelBMFont *instructionsLabelFont = 
        [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"instructions" fntFile:@"TestingFont.fnt"]; 
    CCMenuItemLabel *instructionsItemLabel = 
        [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:instructionsLabelFont 
                                target:self 
                              selector:@selector(instructionsLayer)];

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithTtems:instructionsItemLabel,nil];
    menu.position = buttonHolder.position;
    [self addChild:menu];
}
```

Comment: How do I get the right position for the label for multiple CCMenuItemLabel's?